# simple preg_match not returning expected results

Tags: php, preg-match

I went through a few basics on preg match but its quite difficult when your new to it.

What im trying to do is search for this instance in a string

bug1234

it shouldnt be case sensitive so bug1234 or BuG1234 should work
it must be the word bug followed by any 4 numbers
there should be no spaces or anything in between bug1234 so bug-1234 should not be a match
it should ignore things like bug1234z and abug1234 so it must be bug1234 with nothing prefixing it or coming directly after it unless there is a space between then so "there is a problem with bug1234 that i cant solve" would be a match.

Just to clarify it can be any number not 1234 specifically but they must be 4 digits

Heres my lame attempt:

```
$file_string = $workdetails->text;
$file_string = strtolower($file_string);
$bugkey = "/bug[0-9]{4}/";
$nosey = preg_match($bugkey, $file_string);
if($nosey !== false) 
{
echo "We have a match baby!!"
}
```

That just seemed to return all sorts, empty string,s string with no mention of the word bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the regex to:

```
/\bbug[0-9]{4}\b/i
```

The `\b` modifier will only match on a word boundary so that makes sure it doesn't match things like `abug1234`, `bug12345` or `bug1234was bad`.  I also added the `i` modifier so it is case insensitive.  You no longer need to use `strtolower`.

Also, [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) typically returns an integer, and returns `(int)0` if there is no match.  It only returns `FALSE` on failure.  Therefore you should change the match check to be:

```
if ($nosey > 0) {
// or just
if ($nosey) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/(?ism)bug(?i-sm)[0-9]{4}/`

Tested on the [Regular Expression Test Tool](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php)
With data:

```
sdfsfsbUG1234cccs
```

Cheers!

Comment: FYI the (?ism) part is to apply case insensitivity to that part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
preg_match('/\b(bug\d{4})/i', $file_string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

The [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `i` stands for case insensitive and the `\b` is for a whole word only (word boundary).